# How can I indent JavaScript that's within <script> tags in an HTML file?

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

If I am viewing a HTML file that someone else wrote, it often has `<script>` tags containing javascript, e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video autoplay></video>

        <script>
        var errorCallback = function(e) {
            console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
        };

// Not showing vendor prefixes.
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

    // Note: onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using it with getUserMedia.
    // See crbug.com/110938.
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        // Ready to go. Do some stuff.
    };
}, errorCallback);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to indent the `<script>` tags and the javascript code it contains to some reasonable levels of indentation, using a command like

```
gg=G
```

or visual select the `<script>` tag and hit `=`
How can I do this?

I am setting the

```
let g:html_indent_style1 = "inc"
```

But I believe that only affects newly written code.
I have also tried setting the filetype to javascript, selecting the area and then hitting `=`, none of these seem to work.

Comment: First, you shouldn't reformat that part unless you have to do actual work there. This will create unnecessary changes and pollute your project's history for no reason. Second, you should use [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify).

Comment: @romainl so you mean once js-beautify is installed, I can visually select the javascript and run something like `:'<,'>! node js-beautify` and the code will get filtered? I like it, that would be quite js-beautif**ul**.

Comment: `vnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Leader>t :<C-u>silent '<,'>!js-beautify -j --brace-style=expand -<CR>`

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes Ive been trying to setup something similiar, but using vims own ex mode - as I dont currently have node installed. Ive updated my answer, its close, but not quite indenting correctly

Comment: There's also a [Python version](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/tree/master/python).

Comment: @SatoKatsura ah thanks for the link! Im trying to install the python version now

Comment: You don't _need_ to install it, just add a symlink to the script from somewhere in `$PATH`. But you _can_ install it with `pip install jsbeautifier`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura got it, its working perfectly, thanks. If you want to copy and paste your comments as an answer, I would accept it

Comment: @SatoKatsura maybe post an answer?

Comment: @muru - added another answer based on SatoKatsura's comments, then deleted my original answer for 2 reasons, 1. it was a pretty hacky/rubbish solution and 2. editing by replacing the old with the new answer would have made the existing comments look out of place and non-sensical.

Comment: @muru I would, but I made a [promise](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/editing-text-in-a-quotation-mark/9668#9668) not to intrude on you guys' fiefdoms any longer. Sorry about that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you've helped me out on more than one occasion, your contribution is appreciated by me

Comment: @the_velour_fog There's quite an interesting case study here, apparently there's a point when a given social medium gets too crowded with knowledgeable people for maintaining polite conversation.  Sadly, I'm not knowledgeable enough about these phenomena to enjoy studying them from the inside. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura sigh

Answer (score 2):

Based on @SatoKatsura's comments, here is a shell script (for UNIX like systems) which will install [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) and setup the python  executable as a command.
Just to clarify, this will install the main `js-beautify` repo which contains the `js-beautify` program intended to be run on nodejs, but *this script will not link to the nodejs script* - instead it links to the python executable which is contained in a subfolder.

Generally this would **need to be run as root** - so it can write into `/usr/local/`

```
#===================================
# setup js-beautify - python version
#===================================

git clone "https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify.git" \
                                        /usr/local/src/js-beautify || exit 1

# put a link somewhere in $PATH so js-beautify can be called as a command
if [[ ! -h /usr/local/bin/js-beautify ]]
then
    ln -vs /usr/local/src/js-beautify/python/js-beautify \
                                                  /usr/local/bin/js-beautify
else
    echo "js-beautify link already exists, skipping..."
fi
```

If the script is successful, you can visually select a region in vim and run the ex command:

```
:'<,'>!js-beautify
```

Note: If you have come from the other js-beautify, you will notice the command api for this python version is quite different.
For example, the python command is simpler to run the basic command `js-beautify`. I believe the node version - at a minimum - has a required option or two to get basic functionality to work, e.g. to accept a stream on STDIN.
But overall the python version seems like it might have less options..?