# Editing text in a quotation mark

Tags: normal-mode

I have a line which contains the following text:

```
'some text in the quotation mark' some other text goes here
             ^
       cursor is here
```

What is the fastest way to replace the text within a quotation mark with something else? I mean I want to type something completely different there. Is there a shortcut to remove all text within the quotation and enter to insert mode?

Comment: What's wrong with `ci'` ?!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `c` operator, followed by the `i'` text-object:

```
ci'foo
```

This will turn:

```
'some text in the quotation mark' some other text goes here
```

into:

```
'foo' some other text goes here
```

`:h navigation` will blow your mind.

Comment: *After* you learn the text-objects/motions/operators available by default in Vim, you may want to look at some extra ones, e.g. [targets](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim), providing additional features, or the one Sato Katsura suggested in the now deleted answer ([textobj-quotes](https://github.com/reedes/vim-textobj-quote)).

Comment: @VanLaser, or read up on `:omap` which lets you create your own text-objects without third party tools and libraries *before* going plugin crazy.

Comment: @romainl, not or, and :P

Comment: ... Because once you read about `:omap` your first attempts at creating text objects are guaranteed to outshine a library written by the likes of Kana Natsuno.  Well played Romain, well played.

Comment: Yes, mister plugin developper, there's infinitely more value in customizing Vim than your *kind* would care to admit. Not everything needs to be generic, bloated, opaque, and over-engineered to be useful. Vim's ecosystem is nice and all but Vim *itself* is what powers your crappy useless *product* that nobody actually needs.

Comment: Of course, Vim is perfect and intuitive by design.  Wait, strike that, it's perfect and intuitive by _definition_.  It's just that I sometimes wonder why it needs a knowledgeable yet narcisistic bully to herd the unsuspecting users to the One True Way and shelter them from the propaganda of plugin developers scourge. :)